# SSL Encryption and Cassandra

Tags: java, ssl, encryption, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I am trying to enable client to node SSL encryption however I keep running into the most strangest errors when trying to start DSE after setting `client_encryption_options` as true in **cassandra.yaml**

this is from dse log :

```
ERROR 15:09:42,277  DseModule.java:108 - Unable to start server. Exiting...
com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) An exception was caught and reported. Message: Failed to initialize SSLContext: File '/home/ec2-user/keystore.node2' does not exist
  at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.configure(Unknown Source)

1 error
        at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:466) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:155) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:107) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
        at com.datastax.bdp.ioc.DseInjector.get(DseInjector.java:31) ~[dse-core-5.0.6.jar:5.0.6]
        at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.main(DseModule.java:89) ~[dse-core-5.0.6.jar:5.0.6]
Caused by: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Failed to initialize SSLContext: File '/home/ec2-user/keystore.node2' does not exist
        at com.datastax.bdp.config.DseConfig.init(DseConfig.java:443) ~[dse-core-5.0.6.jar:5.0.6]
        at com.datastax.bdp.DseCoreModule.<init>(DseCoreModule.java:76) ~[dse-core-5.0.6.jar:5.0.6]
        at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.getRequiredModules(DseModule.java:139) ~[dse-core-5.0.6.jar:5.0.6]
        at com.datastax.bdp.server.AbstractDseModule.configure(AbstractDseModule.java:27) ~[dse-core-5.0.6.jar:5.0.6]
        at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.configure(DseModule.java:76) ~[dse-core-5.0.6.jar:5.0.6]
        at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:62) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:340) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:110) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:138) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:104) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
        ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File '/home/ec2-user/keystore.node2' does not exist
        at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.openInputStream(FileUtils.java:299) ~[commons-io-2.4.jar:2.4]
        at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(FileUtils.java:1763) ~[commons-io-2.4.jar:2.4]
        at com.datastax.bdp.util.SSLUtil.createKeyStore(SSLUtil.java:127) ~[dse-core-5.0.6.jar:5.0.6]
        at com.datastax.bdp.util.SSLUtil.initKeyManagerFactory(SSLUtil.java:115) ~[dse-core-5.0.6.jar:5.0.6]
        at com.datastax.bdp.config.DseConfig.resolveKeyManagerFactorySafely(DseConfig.java:831) ~[dse-core-5.0.6.jar:5.0.6]
        at com.datastax.bdp.config.DseConfig.getSSLContext(DseConfig.java:737) ~[dse-core-5.0.6.jar:5.0.6]
        at com.datastax.bdp.config.DseConfig.init(DseConfig.java:439) ~[dse-core-5.0.6.jar:5.0.6]
        ... 14 common frames omitted
```

This is my **cassandra.yaml** file

```
client_encryption_options:
    enabled: false
    # If enabled and optional is set to true encrypted and unencrypted connections are handled.
    optional: false
    keystore: /home/ec2-user/keystore.node2
    keystore_password: cassandra
    require_client_auth: true
    # Set trustore and truststore_password if require_client_auth is true
    truststore: /home/ec2-user/truststore.node2
    truststore_password: cassandra
    # More advanced defaults below:
    protocol: TLS
    algorithm: SunX509
    store_type: JKS
    cipher_suites: [TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA]
```

I am not sure why I keep getting

```
SSLContext: File '/home/ec2-user/keystore.node2' does not exist
```

This is the location of my keystore -

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-18-51-175 ~]$ locate keystore.node2
/home/ec2-user/keystore.node2
```

What am i possibly doing wrong ?

Comment: Can you check the file permissions to make sure the user running Cassandra has access to the keystore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

switch to your cassandra user, and do a `cat /home/ec2-user/keystore.node2` and see if that user can see the file

also run: `ls -lna /home/ec2-user/keystore.node2` and post here.